# multiply 2 time discrete vectors using numpy library (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-requests, jupyter-notebook

I need to Write a function with the next inputs:

`n1`, `x1`, `n2`, `x2` and the function return two outputs `n`, `y`.

`n1` is discrete time array of the signal `x1`. (Discrete time means that the sample of time are integer). `n2` is discrete time array of the signal `x2`. `x1` and `x2` are the values of a signal (such as `sin` or `cos` for example). The purpose of the defined function is the multiply between two signals. `y[n] = x[n1] · x[n2]‏`

basically i need to multiply two ‏time discrete vectors: for example : `X1=[1,2,3,4]` `x2=[1,1,1,1]`

`n1=[-3,-2,-1,0]` `n2=[0,1,2,3]`

vectors `n1`, `n2` are the time vectors witch meet at the time 0. and `X1`, `x2` are ‏their values(amplitude) .

I need to multiply them the answer should be the vector for the time :`[-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3]`

the vector of amplitude: `[0,0,0,1,0,0,0]` because thay meet just in time 0.

need to use `numpy` library functions.
and didn't succeed doing so

please help.

Answer (score 0):

You say you would like to multiply them, but your desired result does not show a multiplication. 
Do you mean to say the vector `y` should contain ones for those values where n1 and n2 "meet", and zeros otherwise?

Will vectors n1 and n2 always contain ordered consecutive integers, as in your example?

--

Once clarified, here is a solution:

```
n = np.arange(n1[0], n2[-1] + 1)
y = np.zeros(n.size) 
y[-n2.size: n1.size] += 1
```

First, `arange` creates an array of consecutive integers from the first element of n1 to the last element of n2, under the assumption that n1 contains lower elements than n2.
An array of `zeros` is created, and finally one is added (`+= 1`) to the elements between the `size` of `n2` starting from the end, and the `size` of `n1` starting from the beginning.

Comment: "mean to say the vector y should contain ones for those values where n1 and n2 "meet", and zeros otherwise?"
bacicly yes, think that you are multipling two signals, each one have his own time, if one of them start at -3 and ends at 0 and the second one start a -1 and ends at 5. the combined time scale is -3 to 5. the  first signal doesnt have values at 1,2,3,4,5 and the second signal doesnt have values at -3,-2,-1. therefore if i want to multiply then the values of the result signal should be 0 wheb thay dont meet and not 0 when thay meet.

Comment: @skyline Added edit after clarification. The answer provided assumes n1, n2 both contain ordered, consecutive integers, and n1 contains lower edge values than n2.

Comment: but i still have problam with the output y of the function. 
the function gets (def ProductSignal(n1,x1,n2,x2):) for inputs.
n = np.arange(n1[0], n2[-1] + 1) solves the output n.
but i still have problem with the inputs of x1,x2.
when i multiply this 2 vectort reling on the time vector (x1 with n1, x2 with n2)
lets say the the inputs are X1=[1,2,3,4], n1=[-3,-2,-1,0],x2=[1,1,1,3],n2=[-1,0,1,2]
acording to the time vector thay meet in time 0 so the outputs :
n=[-3,-2,-1,0,1,2] -  time vector
y=[0,0,3*1=3,4*0=0,0,0]  (zeros couse unmached time and not zeroes couse the mached time [-1,0])

Comment: @skyline You mention functions you have not shown and ask for functionality not included in the original post. Make future questions clear, concrete and comprehensive, with specific examples of desired behavior.